# difference between css height : 100% vs height : auto

Tags: css

I was asked a question in an interview that "what is the difference between the css `height:100%` and `height:auto`?"

Can any one explain?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

`height: 100%` gives the element 100% height of its parent container.

`height: auto` means the element height will depend upon the height of its children.

Consider these examples:

**height: 100%**

```
<div style="height: 50px">
    <div id="innerDiv" style="height: 100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

`#innerDiv` is going to have `height: 50px`

**height: auto**

```
<div style="height: 50px">
    <div id="innerDiv" style="height: auto">
          <div id="evenInner" style="height: 10px">
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`#innerDiv` is going to have `height: 10px`

Comment: I think that in the case of 'height:auto #innerDiv will be `10px + the size it needs for its own content` - see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wf0zo5bu/)

Comment: @Manish Mishra: What is the best responsive design? Setting the height of the child element or the container element, and letting the other to derive its height ?

Comment: I think a good way of thinking about auto is that you are 'unsetting' hight - it's like not having it set.

Comment: I modified the fiddle that BornToCode shared above, to make it more obvious that `auto` causes the element to grow to accomodate BOTH its content, AND its child's content.  In contrast a Fixed height value does not grow (or show) content that cannot fit within the declared height.https://jsfiddle.net/m3f8y6xr/1/ This Answer, I believe, is not sufficiently worded to make it ovbious that the element will grow to include all content, whether it is its own text, or a child's content. Of course it can be argued that its own text is also a child. This provides visual confirmation of the behavior.

Answer (score 10):

height:100% works if the parent container has a specified height property else, it won't work

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if the parent container has height: auto

Answer (score 7):

A *height of 100%* for is, presumably, the height of your *browser's inner window*, because that is the **height of its parent**, the page. An *`auto` height* will be the *minimum height* of *necessary to contain* .

Comment: This isn't necessarily correct if the parent element is one with a defined height that doesn't fit to the size of the browser's window

Answer (score 3):

The default is `height: auto` in browser, but `height: X%` Defines the height in percentage of the containing block.