# dynamic part of the page breaks the layout

Tags: html, css

Good day! The following layout which I will post almost works. Almost. A part of the page is being dynamically loaded. If it loads few elements (0/1/2/3) It is alright. If it is more, the footer of the page isn't pushed back. (which basically is the error). I am posting the entire source code. It is configured to work nicely. To see the error itself simply change the value of the 
`CHANGEME` variable to something larger than 3.

The source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>LayoutTest</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .webbody {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding:0;
            width:900px;
            height:200px;
            max-height:2000px;
        }
        .topHeader {
            width:900px;
            height:50px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding:0;
            background:purple;
        }

        .dynamic {
            width:650px;
            height:400px;
            float:left;
        }

        .sidebar {
            margin-left:50px; 
            width:150px;
            height:400px;
            float:left;
            background:red;
        }
        .footer1 {
            float:left;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding:0;
            width:900px;
            height:20px;
            background:lime;       
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="webbody">
       <div class="topHeader"></div>   
       <div id="main1" class="dynamic"></div>
       <div class="sidebar"></div>
       <div class="footer1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    //this function only loads the dynamic part of the page
    function load() {
        var main = document.getElementById("main1");
        var CHANGEME = 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < CHANGEME; i++) {
            var slot = document.createElement("div");
            slot.className = "slot";
            main.appendChild(slot);
        }
    }
    load();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example is [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XS5Ad/1/).  Basically I have added the following CSS:

```
#main1 { height: auto; }
```

I have also added a border around the slot class so you can see what is happening.  `height: auto` [is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto)

Comment: Thank you, sir. This fixed this problem and probably all my future questions regarding the height property! (I will mark this as the answer when the timer expires)