# Width:auto taking the size of the parent element

Tags: html, css

Good day! I did some reasearch and I read here [difference between css height : 100% vs height : auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto)

that *height-auto* should take the *minimum amount* of space depending on the children's width.

In my case, the property behaves like `width 100%`, taking 100% of it's parent's width

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 .header2 {
            float:left; 
            width:900px;
            height:23px;
            background:red;
        }
.buttonHolder {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:auto;  
    height:24px;
    background:black;
}

.button {
     width:50px;
    height:24px;
     background:blue;
     float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>
      <div class="header2">
                <div class="buttonHolder">
                    <div class="button"></div> <div class="button"></div> <div class="button"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

The question is: Where is my error?

Comment: width:100% will occupy the full width of its container. Here in your case it is the div with class header2.

Comment: Yes, however I am trying to figure out why 'buttonHolder' is taking the entire 'header2'.

Comment: Can you make it clear how you want your 'buttonHolder' div.

Comment: I want it in the middle of the 'header2', with width equal to the sum of it's children. The first part is implemented and working fine. The width part is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.header2 {
            float:left; 
            width:900px;
            height:23px;
            background:red;
            text-align: center;
        }
.buttonHolder {
     display: inline-block;


    height:24px;
    background:black;
}
```

this should work.

Comment: It works, however it breaks the 'margin: 0 auto;' which I use to center the div, so it fixed the question but opens a new bug.

Comment: it is aligning in the center of the .header2 div. if you want total container in the center you can put margin:0 auto for .header2 and remove float:left