# Height: 100% VS Height:auto

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand the following

1. Height: auto;  What does this do?
2. Height: 100%;  What does this do?
3. What is the difference betweem 1 and 2 ? Any examples to explain the difference ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question should be closed. "General Reference"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`height: auto;` means, the `height` of the element will increase according to the content it holds, if you assign fixed `height`, the content overflows, so when you don't know that that your element will contain how much, you set it to `auto`, so the `height` will `auto` increase.

When you set `height: 100%;` so it will take entire vertical space of the container element, so say for example, when the container element is `200px` in height, and you use `height: 100%;` on the child element, it will be `height: 100%;` of the container element = `200px`.

By default, the element's `height` is always set to `auto` unless and until you specify the `height` using `px` `%` or any other unit.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJzS4/) (`height: auto;`) Keep adding content and your element will expand vertically.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/NJzS4/1/) (`height: 100%;`), this will behave just like you are setting some fixed `height` to your element, if the content increases, it will `overflow`. This method only comes handy where you want your child element to take 100% vertical space of the parent container.

Answer (score 2):

1. > `height:100%`: implies the element is going to have the 100% height of its parent container.
2. > `height:auto`:  means, the element will have flexible height i.e. its height will depend upon the height of children elements of it
3. [Click here for difference with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto)

Comment: As an example, if I were to add `margin:5px` to a div with `height:100px`, it would stretch out of its bounds and do 105px. With `height:auto`, it would take the 5px of margin out of the height instead, keeping it at 100px.

Answer (score 0):

reference:http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property

**Content height: the 'height' property**

```
  <percentage>
```

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the
>   root element is relative to the initial containing block. Note: For
>   absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a
>   block-level element, the percentage is calculated with respect to the
>   height of the padding box of that element. This is a change from CSS1,
>   where the percentage was always calculated with respect to the content
>   box of the parent element.

```
auto
```

> The height depends on the values of other properties. See the prose
>   below.
>       Note that the height of the containing block of an absolutely positioned element is independent of the size of the element itself,
>   and thus a percentage height on such an element can always be
>   resolved. However, it may be that the height is not known until
>   elements that come later in the document have been processed.
>
> Negative values for 'height' are illegal.

For example, the following rule sets the content height of paragraphs to 100 pixels:

```
p { height: 100px }
```

> Paragraphs of which the height of the contents exceeds 100 pixels will
>   overflow according to the 'overflow' property.