# Background-image css does not display

Tags: html, css

It's kinda embarrassing but im stuck.
Here is my index.html:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="top_menu">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And this is my style.css:

```
body{ 
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12 px;
}
.wrapper{ width:1680 px; margin:0 auto }
header{float:left; width:100%; min-width:1680 px} 

.top_menu{ background-image:url('../images/top_menu.jpg');}
```

I included the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` tag in the index. 
The root folder contains: the index.html , the css file and the images file (roots children). Can you help me out please?

Comment: If the css file and the image file are in the root itself then change the path to CSS `style.css` and in CSS change the image path to 'top_menu.jpg'

Comment: Is there any content inside of .top_menu? If nothing is in there, height isn't defined and you won't see anything.

Comment: Your `top_menu` seems to have no content, and no explicit height either. Therefor it doesn't have no height, and thus no visible background.

Comment: You could add `min-height: 100px;` to your `.top_menu` so that you could see something

Comment: This is so embarrassing! @austinhedeveloper you were right! there is no height! Omg me!

Comment: @ochi I appreciate your help. Im so embarrassed!

Comment: @Sergiti no worries. nothing to be embarrassed about... we are all here learning :) - cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GolezTrol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/511529/goleztrol) has it right. The header needs an explicit height since there's nothing in the `top_menu` to give it a height.

```
.top_menu{ 
  background-image:url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
  height: 100px;
}
```

If you want to set the height to the background image: [Set size on background image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css)

Further information on how `height` works:

> `height:100%` implies the element is going to have the 100% height of
>   its parent container.
>
> `height:auto` means, the element will have flexible height i.e. its
>   height will depend upon the height of children elements of it

Examples included with the above explanation: [difference between css height : 100% vs height : auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15943054/1085891))

Comment: Yay for me :) (and you)

Answer (score 1):

As JSuar said, you have to make sure yor div has a minimum height or some content. Then, if yo have your images in a folder in the root level maybe you have to put this:

```
.top_menu{ background-image:url('/folder_name/images/top_menu.jpg');}
```

Also, you can check your css code in this site: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input to be sure there isn't code mistakes.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like the `.top-menu` div to adjust automatically (with setting the height manually), an alternative could be to use an `img` tag instead of the CSS `background-image` approach.

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="top_menu">
            <img src="../images/top_menu.jpg" alt="some image">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```