# CSS height: 100% vs height: inherit

Tags: css

I've seen the question asking [the difference between `height: 100%;` and `height: auto;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto), but what's the difference between `height: 100%;` and `height: inherit;`?

I basically want this element's height to fill/match it's container. Would there be a reason to use `100%` over `inherit` or vice versa?

Comment: Have you read what inherit does? If the container does not have a specified height which means it will be auto, then you are going to inherit the auto. Example http://jsfiddle.net/50oaax77/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit

Comment: @j08691 - Note that for the relevance to this question, that MDN document has an important mistake in its first paragraph. The element inherits the *specified value* from its parent, not its computed value. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`height: 100%` will match the height of the element's parent, regardless of the parent's height value.

`height: inherit` will, as the name implies, inherit the value from it's parent. If the parent's value is `height: 50%`, then the child will also be 50% of the height of it's parent. If the parent's size is defined in absolute values (e.g. `height: 50px`), then `height: inherit` and `height: 100%` will have the same behaviour for the child.

Comment: @HashemQolami Great example! I would suggest adding a margin to the child div to visually show that it is contained within the parent.

Comment: Ah, this is the key. I wasn't thinking about percents. If the container has a percent of anything other than 100%, this element certainly wouldn't be doing what I want it to do. I'll accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: @Nepoxx Thanks, I've just updated the example, added a `padding` to the `.parent` including `box-sizing`.

Answer (score 2):

**`height: inherit`** The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element.

**`height: 100%`** Defines the height in percent of the containing block

For examples, [look here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)