# Background image will not appear

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am 100% at a loss as to why I cannot get a `background-image` to display. I have tried multiple different images to rule that out. I have also changed `src` to `url`, changed the `background-size` from `cover` to `auto 100%`. Nothing I do will get the image to display.

Does anyone see why my background image will not display?

```css
#home-img {
 background-image: url("http://cosmotekcollege.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ban4.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-img">
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pphkLmt/)

Comment: Give your div some content or define a height. It has no height as-is

Comment: The `height: auto` won't suffice?

Comment: When in doubt, right click your page and do *Inspect Element*. If you hover over your `<div>` in the code, it'll highlight it on the page, and you'd find out that it has a height of 0px. `height: auto;` will resize the div to fit its content (which is default behavior regardless), however your div *has no content*. Without any content or a set height, it will be 0px tall.

Comment: I think your example pretty much answers that question. A background image is just that, a background image; it occupies no space, so your div is collapsing to the smallest possible space it can.

Comment: `height: auto` will depend on the children's height.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use backgound-image and you don't have content inside div, you always should set height. Here is example https://jsfiddle.net/5pphkLmt/5/

```
<div id="home-img">
        </div>

#home-img {
    background-image: url("http://cosmotekcollege.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/ban4.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 540px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Chrome Inspect, I changed the #home-img height from "auto" to 537px and then the image appeared. So updating the height is one option to fix this issue.

Another option is covered in this SO Q&A entry.

[How to get div height to auto-adjust to background size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600743/how-to-get-div-height-to-auto-adjust-to-background-size)

Answer (score 0):

you should add  `height` to your code or put something in this DIV, just test `height: 100px;` and enjoy it :)