# Dealing with cyclic dependencies of percentage sized boxes css (specifically how to get a max-height)

Tags: css, cyclic-dependency

First shortly, this is a follow up question to [Problem with max-height not working in css grid element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70197689/problem-with-max-height-not-working-in-css-grid-element) where I misunderstood my problem and I would have had to completely rewrite it, so I'm starting a new one, I hope that is fine.

My goal in one sentence is, to have an `overflow: auto` in a box, which has its height governed by its content, but its max-height governed by its parent. A static representation would be:

```css
#ctlsmall {
  height: 50px;
}

#ctlbig {
  height: 210px;
}

#contentsmall {
  height: 50px;
}

#contentbig {
  height: 350px;
}

.content {
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #005500 0%, #9922ee 100%);
  width: 120px;
}

.overflowctl {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.frame {
  height: auto;
  max-height: calc( 100% - 40px );
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #221100;
}

.canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background: #ddccaa;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='ctlbig' class='overflowctl'>
      <div id='contentbig' class='content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='ctlsmall' class='overflowctl'>
      <div id='contentsmall' class='content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problems begin, when I don't want to use fix heights for my `.overflowctl`, because both, `.content` and `.canvas` have unknown sizes. (`.content` in reality is an iframe, and `.canvas` depends on the window size). My naive approach was to just use `height: auto` for `.overflowctl` and `.frame`, as usually the height should be governed by their content, and at the same time a percentage based max-height, as their max-height is set by the parents. This is logical in a natural understanding of those properties, but seemingly it does not work, because in css the combination between a parent-child combination, where the parent size relies on the child and vice versa is problematic and while solving this, the max-properties seem to be changed... It is described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#cyclic-percentage-contribution) and @onkar-ruikar who showed this to me as an answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70197689/problem-with-max-height-not-working-in-css-grid-element) gave some explanation for it. I prepared a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7dm08qz/) to illustrate the problem, with the adapted example from above:

```css
.overflowctl {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#contentsmall {
  height: 50px;
}

#contentbig {
  height: 350px;
}

.content {
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #005500 0%, #9922ee 100%);
  width: 120px;
}

.overflowctl {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.frame {
  height: auto;
  max-height: calc( 100% - 40px );
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #221100;
}

.canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background: #ddccaa;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='ctlbig' class='overflowctl'>
      <div id='contentbig' class='content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='ctlsmall' class='overflowctl'>
      <div id='contentsmall' class='content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70197689/problem-with-max-height-not-working-in-css-grid-element), I somehow had an example where height and max-height worked differently, but I think the above better shows what I actually want, and the problem boils down to the same thing. The ugly solution would be, to get rid of the `.overflowctl`, but then my nice `.frame` (in reality the colors are better...^^) doesn't work anymore with the padding and also the combination of scroll bar and border-radius. I will add it at the end, just to show it, anyways. I would be happy about any hints how I can achieve my goal! :)

```css
#contentsmall {
  height: 50px;
}

#contentbig {
  height: 350px;
}

.content {
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #005500 0%, #9922ee 100%);
  width: 120px;
}

.frame {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.frame {
  height: auto;
  max-height: calc( 100% - 40px );
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #221100;
}

.canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background: #ddccaa;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='contentbig' class='content'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='contentsmall' class='content'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this

```
.frame {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
}
```

This will give a reference for your percentage height.

Full code

```css
.overflowctl {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#contentsmall {
  height: 50px;
}

#contentbig {
  height: 350px;
}

.content {
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #005500 0%, #9922ee 100%);
  width: 120px;
}

.overflowctl {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.frame {
  height: auto;
  max-height: calc( 100% - 40px );
  width: 120px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #221100;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
}

.canvas {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background: #ddccaa;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='ctlbig' class='overflowctl'>
      <div id='contentbig' class='content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='canvas'>
  <div class='frame'>
    <div id='ctlsmall' class='overflowctl'>
      <div id='contentsmall' class='content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS grid and Flexbox have some special behavior related to percentage height.

Related questions to get more details:

[Why does `height: 100%` value 'work' for child tags of grid-items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65115888/8620333)

[Percentage 'min-height' works only when element has indirect parent with 'display: flex'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69755691/8620333)