# How do I prevent the main div from being cut off when I scroll down?

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent the main `div` from being cut off when I scroll down? The text is still there, but the `background-color` and `borders` disappear when I scroll down. Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/coderguybrosk/pen/oNVdWpV), and here is a [screenshot](https://imgbox.com/KTQzJD6p) of how it looks in Firefox.

I have `height:100%` and `bottom:[low number] px`. I can zoom out very far and see the entire div, so it's viewing area-based.

**Here is the html:**

```
<body>

    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="diary.html">diary</a></li>
        <li><a href="fitness.html">fitness</a></li>
        <li><a href="misc.html">misc</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="main">
      <!-- NOTE: no clue why i need that style padding tag but it looks bad without it lol -->
<h1>web dev journal</h1>
<h2>lorem ipsum and stuff</h2>
<h3 class="devdate">2/2/2024 - placeholder</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<h3 class="devdate">2/1/2024 - placeholder</h3>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

  <h3 class="devdate">1/29/2024 - placeholder</h3>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<h3 class="devdate">1/29/2024 - asdas</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
  <h3 class="devdate">1/28/2024 - asdasd</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
  </body>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size:10px;
}
html, body{
    background-image: url(https://i.redd.it/pdcyxx2i2n941.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
/* NOTE:  */
.navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:80rem;
    min-width: 40rem;
    margin-top:1rem;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    background-color: hsl(0,0%,0%);
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
}
.navbar a{
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-left:1.5rem;
    padding-right:1.5rem;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: metrobold;
    font-size:3.2rem;
}
.navbar a:hover{
    color: hsl(240,80%,90%)
}
.navbar li{
    float: left;
}

.main{
    width:80rem;
    min-width: 40rem;
    height:100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-left: 3px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    border-right: 3px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    border-top: 3px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-color: hsl(0,0%,0%);
    line-height:1.5;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;

}

.main h1{
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: metrobold;
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.main h2{
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: metrobold;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
}

.main p {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 65%);
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: metroregular;
    font-size:2rem;
    text-align: left;
}

.main img{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

h3.devdate{
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: metrobolditalic;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `height: 100%` from the `.main`. Height is by default set to `auto`, which will set the height of the `.main` area by its content, while `height: 100%` will set it's height by it's parent container.

This is a good stack page to read more about it: [Difference between css `height : 100% vs height : auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943009/difference-between-css-height-100-vs-height-auto#:%7E:text=height%3A%20100%25%20gives%20the%20element,the%20height%20of%20its%20children.).

```css
.main{
    width:80rem;
    min-width: 40rem;
    /* Height removed from here */
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-left: 3px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    border-right: 3px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    border-top: 3px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-color: hsl(0,0%,0%);
    line-height:1.5;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;

}
```